# How to add two radiobutton on every single row of datagridview in windows application dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net

In windows application I am adding one `datagridview`. I want dynamically add two radio button on each single row.  How can I do this?

Comment: We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question- if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 3):

Article : Build a Custom RadioButton Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.